# How to embed buttons in a Powerpoint presentation to print Word files?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, presentations, kiosk

I want to build a Powerpoint presentation to use in Kiosk mode on a Public PC. The purpose is to fulfill needs for hard-copy forms.  The presentation would contain about 30 buttons, each associated with a different external .doc/.docx file, stored on a local hard drive or a server.  Clicking a button would trigger printing of the associated file.

I assume VBA would be required for this feature, but I have no idea how to go about doing it.  I am hoping someone can show me a generic example of how coding such a button would be accomplished.

Comment: This isn't a code writing service. What have you tried so far? Paste the code you've got working till now.

Comment: Is what you're describing something like a print-on-demand feature?

Comment: I edited the question :)

Comment: This used to be simpler when Word let you print from the command line.  MS seems to have removed this useful feature.  You might want to see if Adobe Reader still supports command line printing.  If so, your buttons could be assigned a RUN action setting, with the run action being full_path_to_Reader.exe /switches as neede full_path_to_PDF_file